# Showing a non-abelian subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbf{C})$ is non-elementary

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

First of all, my knowledge on subgroups of $PSL(2,\mathbf{C})$ is not very good, so please bear with me.

Just for context, I have a hyperbolic Riemann surface and I know it's fundamental group is non-abelian. Since fundamental groups correspond to a group of deck transformations on the covering space, which is the unit disk, this group can be interpreted as a subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbf{C})$.
Apparently, from here, we can deduce that this group is non-elementary (i.e has no finite orbits), but I'm stuck on seeing how this this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know anything at all about elementary subgroups besides just the definition (i.e. has a finite orbit)?

Comment: Not really I'm afraid.. is there a detail I should be using that I'm unaware of?

Comment: So, for example, you don't know about the classification of isometries of the hyperbolic plane, and the fixed point structures of the various classes of isometries?

Comment: I know a little bit on it. For instance, I know subgroups of PSL are either elliptic, parabolic or hyperbolic and I know the fixed point qualities of these types of transformations.

Comment: Well, those are the basic tools needed to solve this problem.

Comment: So, I would need to show that if the subgroup did have a finite orbit, then the fixed point behaviour of an elliptic, parabolic and hyperbolic element wouldn't behave right?

Comment: I'm still really puzzled :/